# Math-type in y-label repeating; ghost line appearing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When I run the below code, my intended graph is created but with two issues:

1. there is an odd grey line at the bottom which I can't track down and delete
2. the math type from the y-label is repeated near the origin.

If you could work out why this is happening and how to stop it I would be much obliged.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,mathbbol,graphics,graphicx,epsfig,ulem,epstopdf,pgfplots,xfrac}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=-7]
\begin{axis}[width=9cm,axis x line=box, axis y line=box, tick align=outside, enlargelimits=true, xlabel={Separation of Charges, cm}, ylabel={F$_E^{-\sfrac{1}{2}}$, N}, ylabel,  yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,/pgf/number format/precision=0,scaled ticks=false}, style={yshift=-0.2cm}, axis line style={-}, tick pos=left, legend pos=north west]
\addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=olive] coordinates {
    (4.55,16.91774221)
    (4.65,15.82338302)
    (4.65,16.02527474)
    (4.85,15.26061779)
    (4.85,15.62893444)
    (4.85,15.82338302)
    (4.95,15.62893444)
    (4.95,16.02527474)
    (5.35,18.27589266)
    (5.95,20.43824264)
    (5.95,20.87897442)
    (6.55,21.34950572)
    (6.55,21.85335349)
    (7.35,25.04749438)
    (8.35,27.79990209)
    (8.35,30.23455951)
};
\addlegendentry{One occurence}
\addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=cyan] coordinates {
    (4.55,17.16516758)
    (4.55,17.42377643)
    (4.75,16.45338269)
    (4.85,15.44148262)
    (5.15,16.45338269)
    (5.35,18.58897266)
    (5.35,18.91871426)
};
\addlegendentry{Two occurences}
\addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=orange] coordinates {
    (4.65,16.23509691)
    (4.75,16.02527474)
    (4.95,15.82338302)
    (5.15,16.68071682)
    (5.95,21.34950572)
    (6.55,22.39464462)
    (8.35,28.94070541)
};
\addlegendentry{Three occurences}
\addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=purple] coordinates {
    (7.35,25.87222104)
};
\addlegendentry{Four occurences}
\addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=black, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] coordinates {
    (4.65,16.10822318) +- (0.2,0)
    (4.75,16.19247315) +- (0.2,0)
    (4.85,15.51565074) +- (0.2,0)
    (4.95,15.82338302) +- (0.2,0)
    (5.15,16.58865761) +- (0.2,0)
    (5.35,18.65354171) +- (0.2,0)
    (5.95,21.06342629) +- (0.2,0)
    (6.55,22.06512210) +- (0.2,0)
    (7.35,25.70075935) +- (0.2,0)
    (8.35,28.94070541) +- (0.2,0)
};
\addlegendentry{Average}
\addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=gray, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] coordinates {
    (4.55,17.21596818) +- (0.2,0)
};
\addlegendentry{Unused}
\addplot[domain=4.55:8.35] {3.70070829*x-1.76190677};
\coordinate (pt) at (axis cs:6.45,12.55);
\draw [black] (axis cs:4.5,15.05) rectangle (axis cs:5.2,17.65);
\draw [dashed] (axis cs:5.2,15.05) -- (axis cs:6.82,14.38);
\draw [dashed] (axis cs:5.2,17.65) -- (axis cs:6.82,19.89);
\end{axis}
\node[pin=70:{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[tiny, xmin=4.5,xmax=5.2, ymin=15.05,ymax=17.65, enlargelimits=false, ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right, xlabel near ticks, xticklabel pos=upper, xtick={4.55,4.75,4.95,5.15}]
    \addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=olive] coordinates {
        (4.55,16.91774221)
        (4.65,15.82338302)
        (4.65,16.02527474)
        (4.85,15.26061779)
        (4.85,15.62893444)
        (4.85,15.82338302)
        (4.95,15.62893444)
        (4.95,16.02527474)
    };
    \addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=cyan] coordinates {
        (4.55,17.16516758)
        (4.55,17.42377643)
        (4.75,16.45338269)
        (4.85,15.44148262)
        (5.15,16.45338269)
    };
    \addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=orange] coordinates {
        (4.65,16.23509691)
        (4.75,16.02527474)
        (4.95,15.82338302)
        (5.15,16.68071682)
    };
    \addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=black] coordinates {
        (4.55,17.21596818)
        (4.65,16.10822318)
        (4.75,16.19247315)
        (4.85,15.51565074)
        (4.95,15.82338302)
        (5.15,16.58865761)
    };
    \addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=gray] coordinates {
        (4.55,17.21596818)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}] at (pt) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Plotted is all data taken over the course of the experiment.  The coloured crosses represent the number of times a particular force was recorded.  The black crosses, which are evenly split along the line of best fit as expected, denote the average at each separation.  The error bars were calculated as detailed in the Error Appendix.}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The thin grey line comes from your use of `pin`. Use `label` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thin grey line comes from your use of `pin`. Use `label` instead.

The repetition of the math is an artefact from the spurious `ylabel` keyword (directly after the proper `ylabel=<label text>`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, xfrac}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=-7]
\begin{axis}[
    width=9cm,
    axis x line=box,
    axis y line=box,
    tick align=outside,
    enlargelimits=true,
    xlabel={Separation of Charges, cm},
    ylabel={$\mathrm{F}_E^{-\sfrac{1}{2}}$, N},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=0,
        scaled ticks=false
    },
    style={yshift=-0.2cm},
    axis line style={-},
    tick pos=left,
    legend pos=north west
]
\addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=olive] coordinates {
    (4.55,16.91774221)
    (4.65,15.82338302)
    (4.65,16.02527474)
    (4.85,15.26061779)
    (4.85,15.62893444)
    (4.85,15.82338302)
    (4.95,15.62893444)
    (4.95,16.02527474)
    (5.35,18.27589266)
    (5.95,20.43824264)
    (5.95,20.87897442)
    (6.55,21.34950572)
    (6.55,21.85335349)
    (7.35,25.04749438)
    (8.35,27.79990209)
    (8.35,30.23455951)
};
\addlegendentry{One occurence}
\addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=cyan] coordinates {
    (4.55,17.16516758)
    (4.55,17.42377643)
    (4.75,16.45338269)
    (4.85,15.44148262)
    (5.15,16.45338269)
    (5.35,18.58897266)
    (5.35,18.91871426)
};
\addlegendentry{Two occurences}
\addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=orange] coordinates {
    (4.65,16.23509691)
    (4.75,16.02527474)
    (4.95,15.82338302)
    (5.15,16.68071682)
    (5.95,21.34950572)
    (6.55,22.39464462)
    (8.35,28.94070541)
};
\addlegendentry{Three occurences}
\addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=purple] coordinates {
    (7.35,25.87222104)
};
\addlegendentry{Four occurences}
\addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=black, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] coordinates {
    (4.65,16.10822318) +- (0.2,0)
    (4.75,16.19247315) +- (0.2,0)
    (4.85,15.51565074) +- (0.2,0)
    (4.95,15.82338302) +- (0.2,0)
    (5.15,16.58865761) +- (0.2,0)
    (5.35,18.65354171) +- (0.2,0)
    (5.95,21.06342629) +- (0.2,0)
    (6.55,22.06512210) +- (0.2,0)
    (7.35,25.70075935) +- (0.2,0)
    (8.35,28.94070541) +- (0.2,0)
};
\addlegendentry{Average}
\addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=gray, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] coordinates {
    (4.55,17.21596818) +- (0.2,0)
};
\addlegendentry{Unused}
\addplot[domain=4.55:8.35] {3.70070829*x-1.76190677};
\coordinate (pt) at (axis cs:6.45,12.55);
\draw [black] (axis cs:4.5,15.05) rectangle (axis cs:5.2,17.65);
\draw [dashed] (axis cs:5.2,15.05) -- (axis cs:6.82,14.38);
\draw [dashed] (axis cs:5.2,17.65) -- (axis cs:6.82,19.89);
\end{axis}
\node[label=70:{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[tiny, xmin=4.5,xmax=5.2, ymin=15.05,ymax=17.65, enlargelimits=false, ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right, xlabel near ticks, xticklabel pos=upper, xtick={4.55,4.75,4.95,5.15}]
    \addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=olive] coordinates {
        (4.55,16.91774221)
        (4.65,15.82338302)
        (4.65,16.02527474)
        (4.85,15.26061779)
        (4.85,15.62893444)
        (4.85,15.82338302)
        (4.95,15.62893444)
        (4.95,16.02527474)
    };
    \addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=cyan] coordinates {
        (4.55,17.16516758)
        (4.55,17.42377643)
        (4.75,16.45338269)
        (4.85,15.44148262)
        (5.15,16.45338269)
    };
    \addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=orange] coordinates {
        (4.65,16.23509691)
        (4.75,16.02527474)
        (4.95,15.82338302)
        (5.15,16.68071682)
    };
    \addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=black] coordinates {
        (4.55,17.21596818)
        (4.65,16.10822318)
        (4.75,16.19247315)
        (4.85,15.51565074)
        (4.95,15.82338302)
        (5.15,16.58865761)
    };
    \addplot[only marks, mark=x, color=gray] coordinates {
        (4.55,17.21596818)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}] at (pt) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Plotted is all data taken over the course of the experiment.  The coloured crosses represent the number of times a particular force was recorded.  The black crosses, which are evenly split along the line of best fit as expected, denote the average at each separation.  The error bars were calculated as detailed in the Error Appendix.}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes.  Thank you.